# Object return type

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm a recently converted PHP developer and one of the biggest issues that I've been having is figuring out return types when using methods. In PHP it's handled automatically but in C# you need to explicitly tell any function what type it expects to return. I'm hoping there is an easy way to find this information out that I'm unaware of.

Here is an example of something I'm working on, maybe the functionality of what I'm trying to do just isn't possible with how I'm trying to accomplish it.

Assume the correct syntax and rest of the code needed to make this work including the SQL query is written above properly, it's not important to my question.

```
public DataTypeHere ExampleFunction()
{
myTable = new DataTable();  
myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();  
myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;  
myAdapter.Fill(myTable);

return myTable;
}
```

Here is the call:

```
dataType Variable;
Variable = ExampleFunction();

GridView1.DataSource = Variable.DefaultView;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

And the HTML below

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView
        ID="GridView1"
        runat="server"
    </asp:GridView>
</form>
```

So the ultimate question would be, what type of variable does myTable need to be returned as in order to use methods like DataBind() on it?

Comment: I strongly suggest looking into Entity Framework, or other ORMs, and probably ASP.Net MVC. `DataTable` and the like are not really used nowadays.

Comment: I agree with HighCore.  Passing a DataTable is 2003'ish, 2005'ish at best.  Here is a "home grown" ORM example.  This home-grown ORM would be the least I would do.      http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13650443/why-is-datatable-faster-than-datareader/15908284#15908284

Comment: "But datatables are so quick and easy".  The maintenance costs of a DataTable will never pay off in the end.  Never.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you're returning a `DataTable`.

```
public DataTypeHere ExampleFunction()
{
    myTable = new DataTable();  // <---- You can see the type here
    myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();  
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;  
    myAdapter.Fill(myTable);

    return myTable;
}
```

Additionally, I don't see where you declared those variables. The information would be there, as well, and you should declare your variables to have the smallest scope possible, in the method where they are used, if possible:

```
public DataTypeHere ExampleFunction()
{
    var myTable = new DataTable();  // <---- You can see the type here
    var myAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();  
    myAdapter.SelectCommand = myCommand;  
    myAdapter.Fill(myTable);

    return myTable;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the helpful response, my issue was I didn't realize a class could also be a data type.

Comment: @bmanhard **All** data types are either classes, structs, enums, or delegates.

Answer (score 4):

you're returning `myTable` which is initialized with `new DataTable()`, so clearly the return type should be `DataTable`

Comment: Derp, I was assuming it needed to be something like string, int, object, etc and none of that was working. This worked perfectly, sometimes the answer is much simpler than you attempt to realize.